# store .each() , html() in single variable or in array for further use

Tags: jquery, html, each

I have tr, I got each html() from each td of tr, now I want to store these values/text to variables for further use, array could be use also, but how? 
**my current function is**

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-edit', function() {
    var vals = $(this).parent().parent().children();
    $(vals).each(function() {
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
});
```

**here is my Console output**
Car Break
51
851
5
48
4
848
54
45792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and simplest way is to use `array` as shown :-

```
var arr=[];
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-edit', function(){ 
    var vals = $(this).parent().parent().children(); 
    $(vals).each(function(){ 
       arr.push($(this).html());  //push elements value in array 
    });
    console.log(arr);  //print array in console
});
```

Comment: @web.bluffer...happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a special function exactly for creating an array based on elements from other collection (array or jQuery object) - `$.map`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-edit', function(){ 
  var vals = $(this).parent().parent().children();
  var htmls = $.map(vals, function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
  });
  console.log(htmls);
  // ... and then do whatever you want with those `htmls`
});
```

BTW, there's no need to wrap `vals` in jQuery object again - `children()` already returns one.